# Images and List Items

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm looking for a way to display an image on a webpage. This image needs to be just to the right of a list item within an unordered list. Preferably, I'd like it to be within the list item tags but just after the text that is within the list item. However, when I place this image within the list item tags, it bumps the image down to the next line. Does anyone know why this is happening and/or a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What html and css are you using? Could you post a live demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Set the image as a background with background-position: center right;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css set your background-image to the image in question, background-position:right, and add the width of the image to the right padding. This would effectively create the illusion of an image appearing the right of the list item.

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, but this feels like a bit of a hack. Shouldn't it be possible to do this using the box model, letting the text and image be boxes that stack left-to-right inside the li somehow?

Comment: On one had you can do it my way, or you can include the image into the LI wrapping the text in a span and have to hack the css anyway to get the box model to feel right or you can take your chances with the ":after" pseudo-class that isnt fully supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Tom Anderson I was trying to do it your way, but couldn't come up with a working solution. That's why I came here.